# How to move div to another row on mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible in bootstrap to move div from one row to another?
I need something like this:

Desktop/tablet:

```
-----------------------------
|Brand               |search|   #row1             
-----------------------------
|Menu:  | MAIN CONTENT      |
|-link 1|                   |   #row2
|-link 2|                   |
|-link 3|                   |
------------------------------
```

Mobile:

```
-----------
|Brand    |    #row1
-----------
|Menu:   =|
|-link 1  |    #row2 (expanding/collapsing navbar with menu and search form)
|-link 2  |
|-link 3  |
| search  |
|         |
| Main    |
| content |    #row2 
| ...     |
| ...     |
-----------
```

On mobile, i need to move search form from #row1 to collapse menu in #row2.

Comment: you want the to move the search?

Comment: One option is duplicating the search area in row #2 and make it visible only on mobile screen sizes.

Comment: You can clone it with jQuery or do as above, use visible-xs class on the one in the side bar, use hidden-xs on the one in the header. GetBootstrap.com got to the responsive utilities section

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There's no way to accomplish this as you currently have it. One possible compromise would be to have the original search box become invisible at a certain screen size and have another search box, identical in functionality, that is shown where you need it at that point. For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        Brand
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="link1"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link2"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link3"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="link4"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="visible-xs-block">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <main>Main Content</main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously you don't want to make a habit of this kind of thing, but sometimes the optimal layout requires you to do things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Gah lost all my rep opening a Bounty and now I can't comment.
Would it be a viable option to start using a framework? Not to promote any framework in particular but personally I started using Zurb Foundation for the reason you have described alone. http://foundation.zurb.com/